# Error filling in empty Numpy array with `np.datetime64` objects

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I've always been confused about the interaction between Python's standard library `datetime` objects and Numpy's `datetime` objects. The following code gives an error, which baffles me.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

b = np.empty((1,), dtype=np.datetime64)
now = datetime.now()
b[0] = np.datetime64(now)
```

This gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast NumPy timedelta64 scalar from metadata [us] to  according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.datetime64` is a class, whereas `np.dtype('datetime64[us]')` is a NumPy dtype:

```
import numpy as np
print(type(np.datetime64))
# <class 'type'>

print(type(np.dtype('datetime64[us]')))
# <class 'numpy.dtype'>
```

Specify the dtype of `b` using the NumPy dtype, not the class:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

b = np.empty((1,), dtype='datetime64[us]')  
# b = np.empty((1,), dtype=np.dtype('datetime64[us]'))  # also works
now = datetime.now()
b[0] = np.datetime64(now)
print(b)
# ['2019-05-30T08:55:43.111008']
```

Note that `datetime64[us]` is just one of a number of possible dtypes. For
instance, there are `datetime64[ns]`, `datetime64[ms]`, `datetime64[s]`,
`datetime64[D]`, `datetime64[Y]` dtypes, depending on the desired time
resolution.

`datetime.dateitem.now()` returns a a datetime with microsecond resolution,
so I chose `datetime64[us]` to match.

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem. Where can I find an "official" documentation page listing all the datatypes? I couldn't find one. The most obvious place, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html, has only 1 instance of the text "datetime", and it wasn't all that informative.

Comment: Googling "numpy datetime64" should lead you to the [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html).